# PyQt, QThread communication, update QLineEdit filed

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I have a piece of code that is running, communication between two threads and status. I have faced with problem how to update QLineEdit field based on emitted value. So far, it works fine with commented lines, but it's not what I am looking for... How to modify show_process function to do the job...some help will be more than welcome?

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST APP!")
        self.home()

    def Label(self, name, width, length, fontSize) :
        label_name = QtGui.QLabel(name, self)
        label_name.move(width,length)
        label_font = label_name.font() 
        label_font.setPointSize(fontSize)
        label_name.setFont(label_font)

    def Field(self, TrueFalse, width, length, startText) :
        field_name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        field_name.setDisabled(TrueFalse)
        field_name.move(width, length)
        field_name.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        field_name.setText(startText)

    def home(self):
        self.Label('TEST1', 10, 60, 10)
        self.Label('TEST2', 10, 120, 10)
        self.Field(True, 130, 60, 'Ready') # first one
        self.Field(True, 130, 120, 'Ready') # second one

        self.start = QtGui.QPushButton("start", self)
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startPressed)
        self.start.move(260, 20)
        self.stop = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.stopPressed)
        self.stop.move(380, 20)

        self.show()

    def startPressed(self): 
        self.get_thread_start = Start_Process('239.200.10.1', 50010)
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.get_thread_start.terminate)
        self.start.setDisabled(True)
        self.get_thread_start.updated.connect(self.show_process)

        self.get_thread_start.start()

    def stopPressed(self):
        self.start.setDisabled(False)
        self.get_thread_start.running = False

    def show_process(self, data):
        if str(data) == '1' :
            #self.textbox1.setText(str(data))
            pass
        elif str(data) == '0' :
            #self.textbox2.setText(str(data))
            pass

class Start_Process(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    running = True

    def __init__(self, mcstaddr, mcstport):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.array = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

    def run(self):

        while self.running:
            for i in self.array :
                self.updated.emit(i)
                time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your problem ?, I have executed your code removing the comments and I have had no problems.

Comment: What do you want to do in show_process?

Comment: You did the signal/slot connection correctly, you just need to keep a reference to the object which you want to update. So adding `self.textbox = label_name` to the end of the `Window.Label` method resolves your issue.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the question! The problem is that Field should be updated according to emitted value - 1, 2, 3...and so on. show_process function should work that... If I am not clear, try to uncomment th lines and comment self.Field(True, 130, 60, 'Ready')

Comment: Every time you call self.Field you are creating a new QLineEdit, and that is not suitable.

Comment: @eyllanesc What do you suggest? How to create several QLineEdit and make a reference to each of them interdependently?

Comment: How much does QLineEdit depend on?

Comment: @eyllanesc it is very important, this information should give some kind of statuses and should be updated at least on every second

Comment: I do not understand what you want, I've tried this [code](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/76e01206e30cfdce4e19e2db49477ef0) and it does what you say.

Comment: @eyllanesc try do delete following lines: 
    self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox.setDisabled(True)
    self.textbox.move(130, 60)
    self.textbox.setText('Ready')
and use only: self.Field(True, 130, 60, 'Ready')
Make a reference to this QLineEdit like self.textbox = field_name and try to run program.
How to add several QLineEdit and control it with different events...

Comment: As I told you in a previous comment with the function self.Field you are creating a QLineEdit every time you call it, and that is not suitable.

Comment: Please specify, how many QLineEdits do you want to create and what are the events?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for misunderstanding. I have modified the code above! Function show_process shall update QLineEdit fields based of reception of "1" or "0", if it is zero it should modify first field, for zero - second one... I hope that is clear now?

Comment: Why do not you want to use the self.textbox1 and self.textbox2 attribute, or are you going to dynamically create the QLineEdits?

Comment: see this: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/76e01206e30cfdce4e19e2db49477ef0

Comment: @eyllanesc looks better now! :)

Comment: Is that what you wanted? To be able to publish it as a response.

Comment: @eyllanesc Absolutely what I wanted to implement! Thanks!

Comment: I will post the answer, please do not forget to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to access the widget is to create a container, in this case we choose a dictionary:

```
self.field_dict = {}
```

Then we add in the `Field()` method we add the `QLineEdits` to the dictionary.

```
def Field(self, TrueFalse, width, length, startText, key) :
    field_name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
    ...
    self.field_dict[key] = field_name
```

Then we can get the `QLineEdit` through the key.

```
def show_process(self, key, data):
    self.field_dict[key].setText(data)
```

**Complete Example:**

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("TEST APP!")
        self.field_dict = {}
        self.home()



    def Label(self, name, width, length, fontSize) :
        label_name = QtGui.QLabel(name, self)
        label_name.move(width,length)
        label_font = label_name.font() 
        label_font.setPointSize(fontSize)
        label_name.setFont(label_font)

    def Field(self, TrueFalse, width, length, startText, key) :
        field_name = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        field_name.setDisabled(TrueFalse)
        field_name.move(width, length)
        field_name.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        field_name.setText(startText)
        self.field_dict[key] = field_name

    def home(self):
        self.Label('TEST1', 10, 60, 10)
        self.Label('TEST2', 10, 120, 10)
        self.Field(True, 130, 60, 'Ready', 0) # first one
        self.Field(True, 130, 120, 'Ready', 1) # second one

        self.start = QtGui.QPushButton("start", self)
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startPressed)
        self.start.move(260, 20)
        self.stop = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.stopPressed)
        self.stop.move(380, 20)

        self.show()

    def startPressed(self): 
        self.get_thread_start = Start_Process('239.200.10.1', 50010)
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.get_thread_start.terminate)
        self.start.setDisabled(True)
        self.get_thread_start.updated.connect(self.show_process)

        self.get_thread_start.start()

    def stopPressed(self):
        self.start.setDisabled(False)
        self.get_thread_start.running = False

    def show_process(self, key, data):
        self.field_dict[key].setText(data)

class Start_Process(QtCore.QThread):
    updated = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, str)
    running = True

    def __init__(self, mcstaddr, mcstport):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.array = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

    def run(self):

        while self.running:
            for i in self.array :
                self.updated.emit(i, str(self.counter))
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.counter += 1

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```